# how to store date and pass values(date) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i storing date in db as below code

```
convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),105)
```

now i need to search values

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spr_tb_sales
@to_date date,
@from_date date
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM tb_sales_
WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN @from_date AND  @to_date
END
```

If I pass in the values 01-01-2014 and 10-01-2014 it's showing error

```
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

where i made error.help me

Comment: You are storing in varchar and the param on proc is date, so better use a varchar in proc param

Comment: Store a date as a date rather than as a varchar? Where are the types/sizes for the two input params?

Comment: Like others have stated, you should use a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field instead of `VARCHAR`. That said, how are you calling the `spr_tb_sales` when you get the syntax error?

Comment: as u said i converted to "convert(date,GETDATE(),105)".how to pass values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing date as a varchar field. This doesn't seem to be a good idea and I believe between won't work on that. You should store date using the datetime type.  Let SQL decide how to store it and you can format it as you wish while displaying.

Comment: as u said i converted to "convert(date,GETDATE(),105)".how to pass values

Comment: Just remove any conversion while storing date field. Make sure that your field type in the table - where you store date - is of date type (because you are using date type as your parameter in the procedure). Once you have this done, your procedure should work as expected.

Comment: date will store in YYYY-MM-dd format right.shall i pass values as dd-MM-yyyy format?

Answer (score -1):

I think from what you are saying it seems like you are passing the dates in incorrectly. when you call your stored procedure, it should look like this:

```
exec spr_tb_sales '01-01-2014', '10-01-2014'
```

I think you might be missing the quotes around your dates which would give you the error that '-' is not correct syntax.